# How to access record's internals in Show/Edit/Create

Tags: admin-on-rest

Similar to [admin-on-rest: Access row's column data within a Datagrid component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44883855/986160) although I think it doesn't apply to my cases:

```
 export const PlantShow = (props) => {
 return (<Show {...props}>
      <TabbedShowLayout>
        <Tab label="Analytics">
            { record.oneId && <MetricsCharts {...props} manufacturer="one" /> }
            { record.otherId && <MetricsCharts {...props} manufacturer="other" /> }
            { record.anotherId && <MetricsCharts {...props} manufacturer="another" /> }
        </Tab>
    </TabbedShowLayout>
 </Show>)
}
```

There should be a way to access current record's internals so I can introduce conditional logic .. I didn't find anything useful in props.. I even tried to inject `{record}` in PlantShow function but that didn't work either. Also `DependentInput` definitely doesn't help here

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use an intermediate component as a child of `Show`. It will receive the record prop.

See https://codesandbox.io/s/wyln51r907 (in `posts.js`, around the `PostShow` component.

Comment: It can be a child component of `Tab` in your case

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:  ```const AllMetricsCharts = ({...props, record }) => (
  <div>
  { record.oneId && <MetricsCharts {...props} manufacturer="one" /> }
  [...]
  </div>
);
``` and I used it as `<AllMetricsCharts {...props}/>` in `Tab`