# Conditional Tab/FormTab rendering in TabbedShowLayout/TabbedForm

Tags: admin-on-rest

I would like to display a `Tab` inside the `TabbedShowLayout` only if the record has a specific property. I tried to create a custom component as below:

```
const EventsTab = ({...props, record}) => {
  return record && record.hasEvents &&
  <Tab label="Tab2">
    test
  </Tab>
}
```

and then add it inside the `Show` layout as:

```
<Show {...props}>
  <TabbedShowLayout>
    <Tab label="Tab1">
      <MetricsComp {...props} />
    </Tab>
    <EventsTab {...props}/>
  </TabbedShowLayout>
</Show>
```

but I get the following error: `uncaught at finalize Invariant Violation: EventsTab(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.`

`Admin-on-rest` allows conditional rendering of a component (like in [How to access record's internals in Show/Edit/Create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809402/how-to-access-records-internals-in-show-edit-create)) but not a `Tab`. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had to do something similar - Unfortunately we don't have access of record in `Show` but we have in `TabbedShowLayout`. So we decided to create  a custom `TabbbedShowLayout` with render() of `TabbedShowLayout` changed like that:

```
render() {
    const {
        children,
        contentContainerStyle,
        record,
        resource,
        basePath,
        translate,
        version,
    } = this.props;
    let changedChildren = children;

    if (record.excludeTab) {
        changedChildren = [];

        for (let i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
            if (children[i] instanceof Array) {
                changedChildren.push(children[i]);
            } else if (children[i] instanceof Object 
                       && children[i].props.label !== "TabToExcludeLabel") {
                changedChildren.push(children[i]);
            }
        }

    }
    return (
        <div style={divStyle} key={version}>
            <Tabs
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                contentContainerStyle={contentContainerStyle}
            >
                {React.Children.map(
                    changedChildren,
                    (tab, index) => ....
    )
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure and I may be being presumptuous but you component EventsTab will basically return a boolean and not a valid react component. Is the below what you are looking for?

```
const EventsTab = ({...props, record}) => {
  return record ? record.hasEvents ?
  (<Tab label="Tab2">
    test
  </Tab>): null: null
}
```

Comment: this resolves the problem of the error thrown but it creates a Tab with no title! this should be because of problematic behavior of TabbedShowLayout